# How to check results of data load from aws S3 to Snowflake

Tags: load, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Could anyone possibly advise me on how I can check the results of my data load from S3 to Snowflake.

The load process is batch oriented where I drop files to a S3 bucket from where in Snowflake, we ingest the data into permanent tables by querying stages that read from the files.

Once the data from a file is processed the file needs to be moved to an archive folder.

I'm struggling with how I can complete the last step?

I see a few options in mind but not sure how good they are
option 1 - an external function in Snowflake that will raise an event in AWS that will trigger a lambda function to move the file. I think it's a bit flaky

option 2 - write load results into an audit table in Snowflake then then from aws poll this table and move all files listed in it as processed to the archive - might work, but a bit old school, also not real time so will require extra querying on Snowflake side to prevent duplicates

option 3 - write a file straight to the stage and archive folders and delete it from Snowflake using delete option of the load command - not ideal and a bit workaround-ish.

Many thanks in advance. I guess no need to tell that I'm a newby for Snowflake :-)

Answer (score 0):

All of those options are viable, actually. Just depends on your preference. One note, though, on option 2. You do not need to create an audit table. You can get to a load history of a specific table or tables directly in Snowflake. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/copy_history.html

Comment: Thanks Mike. I decided to proceed with the pipes as it's an easy option even if it comes with certain limitations. One of the things I can't figure out is how to trigger procesing donw the stream - just Snowflake does not support triggers. So I can load a stage table thorough the pipe and after that I can't process the data seamlessly.

Comment: You can use Streams along with Tasks to simulate a trigger.  A Stream is added over the table that the data is being loaded into.  A task is running on a frequent basis with a WHEN SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA = True option.  Once something lands in the stream, the task will see new data and execute the statement in the Task.  There are many good examples in the Docs or on Community that can help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it in one of my recent migrations. By the way I did not understand the need to write the file in S3. You can write directly to an internal stage which is much more safe and secure. Snowflake automatically encrypts data in S3. If you copy file to S3(I am assuming you are using external stage), you will be responsible to keep it secure. Any way,  how I incorporated the archive process in my migration is as below.

I used Python for generating a CSV dump from SQLSERVER using BCP on a linux server. The python framework then splits the file and compresses it using the LINUX SPLIT and GZIP commands. Post that, it does a 'PUT' to the snowflake internal stage. I check the output of the PUT and if it is a success, I move the file to an archive folder on LINUX. We have a batch program which runs weekly to cleanup the archive folder.

Comment: Thanks Rajib, as I understand you orchestrate everything from a Python scrpt and that your assumtion is that once the file is in the internal storage you archive the original extract. That makes sense to make an assumtion that the responsibility of the Python script is to deliver the file to the internal storage. Unfortunately in our case we need to know the outcome of the copy into and ideally trigger an event.

Comment: Hi Andrey, your assumption is right. I do not know how will you achieve that in your use case without having something poll the status of the process. I have not seen trigger support within Snowflake yet. I am little cautions about polling mechanisms especially if it is on cloud.